# running applications using MySQL

Tags: dependencies, packaging

(I'm not sure this is the right forum, but if it is not, please forgive me, and please point me to the right forum)

If I am writing an application that uses MySQL as the database. Is it possible to package the application such that when one installs it on a machine that doesn't have MySQL, the application still runs?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Only if you setup a remote mySQL server. They would need mySQL. Since mySQL is free you could have them install it.

I'd consider using SQlite instead. As it's just text files and much more easily integrated into an application.

http://www.sqlite.org/

Comment: (I'm sticking with MYSQL, for other various reasons) Sorry, I don't get your answer. So say, if my application needs to use a database to store/retrieve/manage data, then do I or do I not need to pre-install MySQL on the machine on which the application is going to run?

Comment: You'd have to pre-install it then on any computer your app would run (assuming its using a local database and you're not trying to do something with a central server). You can bundle mySQL with your app but then you have to release it as GPL licence and follow a bunch of rules. Its easier to just have mySQL be a requirement.

Comment: I see. That makes sense. Thanks! Do you know of any other database management apps/services that would allow you to use without having to install it? Maybe some database put on a server that allows access through http/ftp or some other forms of connection?